# Scala Equality: Why does this code compile?

Tags: scala

There is one particular issue in scala which bites me every time. and each time it bites me ... it bites very hard...

why does this line compile

```
val x = "10"
if (x != 10) {
   print("do something")
}
```

This line compiles and executes but for a "typesafe" language like scala ... this line should result in an compile error

Comment: You should look at scalaz `===` operator to get what you want.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30243825/4080476

Comment: Why do you think it should not compile? `10` does not equal to `"10"`, so the result you are getting is correct. Why do you think it should be impossible to compare objects of different types?

Comment: `==` is simply a method, not an operator, how would you do it differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the ancestor of all types is Any, and Any defines method `!=`. See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any

So the compiler bends backwards to make your code compile, and goes up the type hierarchy of `String("10")` until it finds an implementation of `!=` that takes an integer

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching gives you a bit more help.

```
scala> val i = 17
i: Int = 17

scala> "42" match { case `i` => }
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: String
       "42" match { case `i` => }
                         ^

scala> case class C(i: Int)
defined class C

scala> 42 match { case C(_) => }
<console>:14: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : C
 required: Int
       42 match { case C(_) => }
                       ^
```